# How Can I reset Html form's value with php?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
class islem
{   
    function topla($a,$b,$c)
    {
        $c=$a + $b;
        return $c;
    }
}

if ($_POST) {
    $a=intval($_POST['a']);
    $b=intval($_POST['b']);
    $c=intval($_POST['c']);
    $toplama=new islem;
} 
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    Sayı 1
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Sayı 2
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    Sonuç
    **<input type="text" name="c" value="<?php echo $toplama->topla($a,$b,$c);?>">**
    <br>
    <button>Gönder</button>
    <button type="reset" value="Temizle">Temizle</button>
</form>
```

I can reset input text fields, but how can I reset Post['C'] text fields? 
When I click the `reset(temizle)` button, adding on its

Answer (score 0):

The reset button will reset the form fields to what they were **when the page was loaded**. In this case, you have pre-filled content in your form, so clicking reset will simply undo any user changes since the page-load.

Here is an example of how you can reset the form fields that have pre-loaded data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
       $("#form")[0].reset();
   });
});
```